# Getting NullPointerException on context.getPackageManager() - not sure why

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i am trying to  get a list of social media clients on a phone in my Android code. i cant see why, but i am getting a nullpounterexception at the init'ing of List
Do i need permissions in manifest to do this? All i have is this method and abutton to call it.

```
public Intent findSocialMediaClients() {

    final String subject;
    final String body;

    subject = "Great Event to tell you about";
    body = "test";

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    List<ResolveInfo> tempActivities = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0); // error here!
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>(); ....
```

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace. And where is `context` initialized?

Comment: Sorry my bad, jsut as i posted i tried to set context from 'this.ciontext' to just 'this' and it worked :)